# getElementsByName not working

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

Looked up several "Answers" to this problem, but it was mostly just people not treating the result returned by getElementsByName() as a NodeList!

Edit: I am trying to hide/show elements based on an element being clicked.  I *could* hardcode this using document.getElementById and just add one everytime I have an element I want to hide/display.  But it would be ideal if I could retrieve all elements named something and just run a loop on them to hide/show.  Then I could just tag an element with a name when writing and this loop would work without alteration.  Below my code is simply trying to popup an alert with the value for testing purposes.  As for now, it consistently breaks with a null error.  I am using and designing for internet explorer 9 as this is what the company uses.

Code:

```
    <input type="radio" name="Area" value="Engineering" id="EngineeringCheck" onclick="javascript: ShowContentEngineering();" />Engineering

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowContentEngineering() {
        alert(document.getElementsByName('EngineeringAreas')[0].value)
        document.getElementById('InformationBlock').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<h5 name="EngineeringAreas" value="luls"> WHAT THE HECK </h5>
```

Code above breaks saying that the object at getElementsByName('EngineeringAreas')[0] is null.  Clearly, right below it, it is not null...  Am I confusing getElementsByName('string')[0].value with the value of the element? Or is it retrieving some other value?

Ideally, I'd add other elements later, tag them with "EngineeringAreas" and never have to mess with the hide/show function.

Edit: Here is the error message:

```
Unhandled exception at line 53, column 9 in http://localhost:57264/Home/Index

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined
```

Comment: Side note, `onclick="ShowContentEngineering();` not `onclick="javascript: ShowContentEngineering();`

Comment: What browser are you trying this on? I tried it in Firefox 41.0.1 on a Mac and it works as expected (it alerts undefined, but that's because headings don't have values, but if I change value to id both places, I get luls).

Comment: What is the alert box supposed to display—luls or WHAT THE HECK?

Comment: @blm Do you mean if you change to getElementById()?  I'll update the post to be more clear.

Comment: @JonKantner Whatever .value should be.  Just something to indicate that it retrieved the element.  I'll update my post to be more clear.

Comment: No, change the `.value` to `.id` and change the `value` attribute in the `<h5>` to an `id` attribute. Then I get "luls" instead of "undefined". However, in no case (and I've tried 3 different browsers now) am I getting `getElementsByName('EngineeringAreas')[0]` as null.

Comment: @blm There is no "id" property for me for getElementsByName('string')[0] according to VS.  I get the following error no matter what I do: "Unhandled exception at line 53, column 9 in http://localhost:57264/Home/Index

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined"  Replace 'value' for any property I try, it's the same error message.  It's not finding it.

Comment: Are you literally doing `getElementsByName('string')[0]`, or is that just for the comment? If it's just for the comment and you are really doing `getElementsByName('EngineeringAreas')[0]` in your test, then IE is doing something different than Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, and I don't have an IE to try it on.

Comment: As a kind of wild stab in the dark :-), what if you do `getElementsByName('EngineeringAreas').item(0)` instead?

Comment: Try using proper HTML, wrapping your elements in a <body> element etc, `document.getElementsByName` has a history of being buggy and not so well supported in many browsers. I'd advise avoiding it, actually, or use jQuery instead for fancy selecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go... seems:

1. `onclick="javascript:` <--- not necessary - just reference the function name
2. `ShowContentEngineering` needs to be set in the window context
3. You're referencing the "value" attribute of an element that doesn't allow value attributes (h5)

I made it work instead grabbing the innerHTML of the h5
Code

```
<input type="radio" name="Area" value="Engineering" id="EngineeringCheck" onclick="ShowContentEngineering();" />Engineering

<h5 name="EngineeringAreas"> WHAT THE HECK </h5>
<script>
    window.ShowContentEngineering = function() {
        alert(document.getElementsByName('EngineeringAreas')[0].innerHTML)
        document.getElementById('InformationBlock').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mu970a8k/

Answer (score 3):

Insert `.attributes[1]` between `.getElementsByName('EngineeringAreas')` and `.value`. The 1 points to the second attribute in the `<h5>` element named EngineeringAreas, which is `value`. Placing `.value` after `.attributes[1]` should return the value text “luls” in the alert box. The alert code should then be set up like this:

```
alert(document.getElementsByName('EngineeringAreas')[0].attributes[1].value);
```

**More Info**: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_attr_value.asp